# Error [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am facing an issue while implementing MultiBinding using dagger 2.2. I am using dagger with MVVM architecture. I have injected the `ViewModelProvideFactory` constructor and binds the dependency from module.

I have followed the tutorial of Mitch from youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DToD1W9WdsE&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC&index=13

I have searched on these links for the solutions but still facing the same issue.

[Dagger2: ViewModel cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399582/dagger2-viewmodel-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method)

[Dagger/MissingBinding java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends ViewModel>,Provider<ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669810/dagger-missingbinding-java-util-mapjava-lang-class-extends-viewmodel-provide)

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478

**Code Snippet**

**ViewModelKey**

```
@MapKey
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

**ViewModelFactoryModule**

```
   /**
 * ViewModelFactoryModule responsible for providing [ViewModelProviderFactory]
 *
 * Annotated with Module to tell dagger it is a module to provide [ViewModelProviderFactory]
 *
 * Annotated with bind annotation to efficiently provide dependencies similar to provides annotation
 */
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelProviderFactory) : ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

**ViewModelProviderFactory**

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelProviderFactory @Inject
constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
    if (creator == null) { // if the viewmodel has not been created

        // loop through the allowable keys (aka allowed classes with the @ViewModelKey)
        for ((key, value) in creators) {

            // if it's allowed, set the Provider<ViewModel>
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                creator = value
                break
            }
        }
    }

    // if this is not one of the allowed keys, throw exception
    if (creator == null) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
    }

    // return the Provider
    try {
        return creator.get() as T
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }

}

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "ViewModelProviderFactor"
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/fazal/Documents/fazal/demo/AdvanceDagger2/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/advancedagger2/di/AppComponent.java:22: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.example.advancedagger2.BaseApplication> {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.example.advancedagger2.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderFactory(viewModelsMap)
      com.example.advancedagger2.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderFactory is injected at
          com.example.advancedagger2.ui.AuthActivity.viewModelFactory
      com.example.advancedagger2.ui.AuthActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.example.advancedagger2.di.AppComponent → com.example.advancedagger2.di.ActivityBuilderModule_ContributeAuthActivity.AuthActivitySubcomponent]
```

I have downgraded the Kotlin version but still facing the same issue. Tell me what, I am doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

I am also providing ViewModel through AuthViewModel which is on the scope of activity. When activity destroys its component and dependencies also destroy.

**AuthViewModelModule**

```
@Module
abstract class AuthViewModelModule {

    /**
     * Binds the auth view model dependency with [ViewModelKey] to group similar [ViewModel]
     *
     * Under the hood it is providing [com.example.advancedagger2.viewmodel.AuthViewModel]
     */
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AuthViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindAuthViewModel(authViewModel: AuthViewModel) : ViewModel
}
```

**ActivityBuilderModule**

```
/**
 * This Class {@linkplain ActivityBuilderModule} is responsible for for android injection
 * for the activity with in the application to avoid the seprate injection in each activity
 *
 * {@linkplain dagger.android.AndroidInjection#inject(Activity)}
 *
 * {@link com.example.advancedagger2.viewmodel.AuthViewModel} can be access from Auth Activity
 * only so it is the concept of sub-modules
 *
 */
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
            modules = AuthViewModelModule.class
    )
    abstract AuthActivity contributeAuthActivity();
}
```

Comment: Your factory probably shouldn't be `@Singleton`. It's lightweight, doesn't carry any state, and your viewmodels probably get bound in an activity related scope and aren't available in `@Singleton` anyways

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the comment I have solved the issue

> Your factory probably shouldn't be @Singleton. It's lightweight,
>   doesn't carry any state, and your viewmodels probably get bound in an
>   activity related scope and aren't available in @Singleton anyways

I have annotated factory with `@Singleton` which cannot be available in activity scope. I have just removed the `@Singleton` annotation. Everything is working as expected

Comment: You saved me! I was trying to find this problem several hours... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add provides annotated method for your view models, see below.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(value = SomeViewModel.class)
abstract ViewModel bindSomeViewModel(SomeViewModel viewModel);


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Binds
abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
```

Comment: can you provide detailed code. where do we provide this.